# AM4 RAID-driver install on existing Win10 without wanting to actually use a RAID-setup

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd, raid

I have had an Issue for a few weeks now, where my OS (windows10) just locks and doesnt work until you restart it. Looking through the event viewer lead me to this solution:

https://forums.overclockers.com.au/threads/micron-ssd-win10-os-lock-kernel-power-41-enhancedstorage-ehstortcgdrv.1210045/

It fits my Setup and how the issue behaves perfectly and the events in event viewer are basicly the same too, so I'm pretty sure that this is the issue I am dealing with.

I have a MSI B350m PRO-VDH Motherboard, so I followed the above solution and went to the product-site and got the PIDE/SATA-Drivers (link to the site: https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350M-PRO-VDH#down-driver&Win10%2064) and noticed that there are six diffrent folders with *.inf-files in them but only one controller. I tried to find any usefull information on what they all mean, but I still don't know, which one I should install. There is no readme anywhere to be found and all information on how to setup RAID seems to happen at the time of installation of windows.

Now, I am not really experienced with troubleshooting in windows and I am certainly not trying to setup a RAID-Configuration and I'm a bit scared that, if I install the wrong storage-controller, my windows won't boot anymore and I have to reinstall it (I went through various threads, where people had problems with their drives and that seemed to be the only solution).

So, long story short: Can I just install the RAID_SATA/rcbottom-driver for my storage controller and therefore hopefully resolve the issue without destroying my whole OS? Or should I install some other driver?

Sorry for the lengthy description for a more or less simple question, but I wanted to make sure people with the same issue will find this thread in the future.

Comment: Weird, the link works for me, but oh well. The autor of the thread figured out that Win10 was overriding the mobo chipset and the micron SSD host contoller, causing the lock ups and fixed the issue by installing storage controllers provided by his mobo (mobo meaning motherboard I guess). When I try to install, Windows gives my a compatibility-warning, but it seems like it would work. Which is the device in question? My SSD or my motherboard/chipset?

Comment: So I looked at the inf-file and the only comments were:

'
; - This version supports Windows 10.
; - Class and ClassGUID specify the type of driver and must match
;     (see $DDKPATH/inc/api/devguid.h).
; - Driver provided by Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. for AMD-RAID 9.2 software.
;   (9.2.0-00127)
'
Since the class and classGUID of the rcbottom-driver matched with the storage controller already installed, I went ahead and installed it and tried to restart, but the pc would not boot properly. I fixed it with the system recovery tool, but now i have the old driver again...

Comment: I finally took a link at that thread, they described a problem with an Intel based system, you have an AMD based system.  Their suggestion worked for them for entirely different reasons.  MSI has not published the drivers your looking for sadly, the drivers your asking about, are not applicable to your scenario

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the help. Probably going to start a new thread then, with the original issue as main topic.