# Windows10 OS-Lockdown, likely because of Windows Storage Controller and Micron Crucial SSD-Harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ssd, crash

so my OS goes in complete lockdown (no mouse or keyboard response) roughly once a day now (only fixed by rebooting) and I decided to do something about it. After some research, I found out that the lockdown is probably shown as a critical-"Kernel-Power"-event in the event viewer and is always preceded by an error with the source "Microsoft-Windows-EnhancedStorage-EhStorTcgDrv". After some more research I found following thread:

https://forums.overclockers.com.au/threads/micron-ssd-win10-os-lock-kernel-power-41-enhancedstorage-ehstortcgdrv.1210045/

This describes my problem pretty accuartely, except that there is one more error with the following signature before every lockdown:

'''
- System

- Provider

  [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-EnhancedStorage-EhStorTcgDrv 
  [ Guid]  {aa3aa23b-bb6d-425a-b58c-1d7e37f5d02a}

  EventID 10

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 1

  Opcode 57

  Keywords 0x8000000000000000
- TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2020-04-01T19:04:13.721708500Z

  EventRecordID 4713

  Correlation
- Execution

  [ ProcessID]  4 
  [ ThreadID]  8

  Channel System

  Computer DESKTOP-0SPFNHM
- Security

  [ UserID]  S-1-5-18

  - EventData

  Description AuthenticateSession 
  Param1 0x1 
  Param2 0x60000001c 
  Param3 0x900000006 
  Param4 0x0 
  CmdStatus 0x12 
  '''

After I updated all the drivers and the issue still happened, I tried to follow the solution in the thread above and even made another thread about it here 
([AM4 RAID-driver install on existing Win10 without wanting to actually use a RAID-setup](https://superuser.com/questions/1538309/am4-raid-driver-install-on-existing-win10-without-wanting-to-actually-use-a-raid)) just to find out, that since I have an AMD based system and not an Intel based one, the solution doesn't apply to me and MSI did not release any drivers I could install instead of the microsoft-storage-contoller. So it seems like I am back to square one. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue on an AMD based system?

Comment: When you say you updated all drivers, did you also update BIOS?  You should do that.